# How do I mark a voice message as listened to using pyrogram?

Tags: pyrogram

I wrote a user bot that uses the stt service to recognize voice messages. Everything works, but I want the voice message to be marked as listened to.

I didn't find any parameters or methods in the documentation to do this. `Client.read_chat_history()` does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no method to mark a voice message as listened via Pyrogram. Consider using a database to store the ID of listened voice message.

Comment: It is sad
I needed it purely for appearance, so that it would be clear to the user that his message had been processed. But it's not critical, so